# Sorting on facet count in search:search

Tags: xquery, marklogic, faceted-search, marklogic-8

I want to sort results on the basis of facet count. How can I go that in search:search?

As of now, I am using this query -

```
let $options := 
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <return-metrics>false</return-metrics>
  <return-facets>true</return-facets>
  <return-results>false</return-results>
  <additional-query>{cts:query($cts-query)}</additional-query>
  <constraint name="decade">
    <range type="xs:dateTime" facet="true">          
      <bucket lt="2002-01-01T00:00:00Z" ge="2001-01-01T00:00:00Z" name="2001">2001</bucket>
      <bucket lt="2003-01-01T00:00:00Z" ge="2002-01-01T00:00:00Z" name="2002">2002</bucket>
      <bucket lt="2004-01-01T00:00:00Z" ge="2003-01-01T00:00:00Z" name="2003">2003</bucket>
      <bucket ge="2004-01-01T00:00:00Z" name="2004">2004</bucket>
      <facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>
      <element ns="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/core" name="released-on"/>
    </range>
  </constraint>
  <operator>
    <state>
      <sort-order direction="descending" type="xs:integer">
        <score/>
      </sort-order>
    </state>
  </operator>
</options>

let $date-seq := search:search("*", $options)
return $date-seq
```

I want to change the options so that I can sort the facet results by facet count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tried this with buckets, but normally I think you'd add facet-options "frequency-order" and "descending":

```
<constraint name="decade">
  <range type="xs:dateTime" facet="true">          
    <bucket lt="2002-01-01T00:00:00Z" ge="2001-01-01T00:00:00Z" name="2001">2001</bucket>
    <bucket lt="2003-01-01T00:00:00Z" ge="2002-01-01T00:00:00Z" name="2002">2002</bucket>
    <bucket lt="2004-01-01T00:00:00Z" ge="2003-01-01T00:00:00Z" name="2003">2003</bucket>
    <bucket ge="2004-01-01T00:00:00Z" name="2004">2004</bucket>
    <facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>
    <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
    <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
    <element ns="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/core" name="released-on"/>
  </range>
</constraint>
```

Comment: Can I add multiple levels of sorting in it? Like, for first level I sorted on frequency-order, for second level I want to sort on facet name.

Comment: I don't believe so. Facet options for ordering are "frequency-order" and "item-order".

Comment: Thanks Dave. This won't have any impact. I can do what I intend with these two options only.